# Android studio 3.3.1 gradle 4.10.1 make project BUILD FAILED

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

> I created a new project and made "Make Project" and failed.

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:preDebugBuild
Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript
Task :app:checkDebugManifest
Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
Task :app:prepareLintJar
Task :app:generateDebugSources
Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug
Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug
Task :app:generateDebugResValues
Task :app:generateDebugResources
Task :app:mergeDebugResources
Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests
Task :app:processDebugManifest
Task :app:processDebugResources
Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Task :app:compileDebugNdk NO-SOURCE
Task :app:compileDebugSources
Task :app:mergeDebugShaders
Task :app:compileDebugShaders
Task :app:generateDebugAssets
Task :app:mergeDebugAssets
Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug
Task :app:mergeLibDexDebug
Task :app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug
Task :app:mergeProjectDexDebug
Task :app:validateSigningDebug
Task :app:signingConfigWriterDebug
Task :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
Task :app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ‘:app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug’.
Internal error when trying to read zip file ‘C:\Users\james52.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\67ba81e89842cc3e1a0ff84b0e9b8d8f\jars\classes.jar’.

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 14s
24 actionable tasks: 24 executed'

> grandle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
google()
jcenter()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
google()
jcenter()

}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
applicationId “com.example.myapplication”
minSdkVersion 28
targetSdkVersion 28
versionCode 1
versionName “1.0”
testInstrumentationRunner “android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner”
}
buildTypes {
release {
minifyEnabled false
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile(‘proguard-android-optimize.txt’), ‘proguard-rules.pro’
}
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: ‘libs’, include: [’*.jar’])
implementation ‘com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0’
implementation ‘com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3’
testImplementation ‘junit:junit:4.12’
androidTestImplementation ‘com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2’
androidTestImplementation ‘com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2’
}
```

Comment: all these funny `“` and `‘` are syntax error ...the chances are slim, that this would build.

Comment: I am facing same issue, did you found out any solutions ??

Answer (score 1):

change the build:gradle version at PROJECT LEVEL TO VERSION TO android studio version